# How can I tell who owns a particular piece of property on a map?

Tags: maps

I already saw mentions of maponics and reportall but they both seem to be address specific one by one sort of tools.

I basically would like to know who owns various pieces of land...ideally if I can see that data with a simple map overlay. I read there was a way to do this in google maps but I can't get that sorted.

It doesn't have to be free, it could be an online service I can use myself or it could be someone that I pay it doesn't really matter. I just want to be able to send a link or screenshot to a particular section of google maps and get the owner/availability/price so that I can make contact and purchase the land.

Comment: Sorry I don't know the answer (nor whether the question fits) but what I am fairly sure about is that you'll need to say what country you are talking about.

Comment: I've seen parcels in Google, but not ownership data. That would be a massive undertaking; it's hard enough for many counties to keep updated.

Comment: This is a massive privacy concern. Most places have this information, but it is controlled by local authorities. Many of them do not have it digitally-spatially available. You may have a very tough time finding what you want, especially if you want it for free.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of information is available in cadastral database, which are usually managed by local authorities. There are usually privacy policies around it, so you'll need to be authorized in order to have this information in most countries. Sometimes the location of the parcels is available, but you then have a code that has to be linked with the owner in another database.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on where you are. In the US For instance, where I live, in WI, most county governments have map viewers like this [one](http://washburncowi.wgxtreme.com/). Where I used to live, in MI's Upper Peninsula, most County governments were still using paper maps. You also have the option of buying plat books if you are looking at specific areas.